# Laracasts Flash Duplicates

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider for flashing messages and I have some code like this at the end of a store method in a controller:

```
     flash()->overlay('Member Invited', 'Success!');

    return view('family.index')->with(['id' => $family->id]);
```

This works as designed.  When a member is invited via a form, the form processed, stored and returned to the page and I am flashed the message.

However, when I go to any other page, I am flashed the same message again. It only does it one page past the original flashing.  I have no idea what would cause this.  I thought once you went to the next request, the flashed data was wiped. Anyone?

Comment: I would suggest you expend your code for those who are not familiar with Laracast and the FlashServiceProvider

Comment: Here is the code:

https://github.com/laracasts/flash

Comment: I'm having the same problem with October CMS (based on Laravel). But I can't figure out how to implement any `Session::forget('flash')` type solution. Not sure what session key October is using, or if there may be complications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the package.  There is a solution here:

https://github.com/laracasts/flash/issues/32

Add the Session::forget call:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))
<div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

    {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
</div>
{{ Session::forget('flash_notification') }}
@endif
```